# How to fix ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE for my url

Tags: nginx

I have this domain [backtocart.co](https://backtocart.co) on godaddy. And I have this subdomain - [app.backtocart.co](https://app.backtocart.co)

Whenever I go to that subdomain I get browser response

`app.backtocart.co didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

Here are the dns configs from godaddy.

[image]

As you can see the root points to a different ip than the subdomain. On `145.239.24.196` I have nginx server.[chatservice.backtocart.co](https://chatservice.backtocart.co) is on nginx as well however it works fine I get nginx response. My nginx configs seem to be fine as well. Here are the configs

```
#proxy_cache_path  /home/html_catch  levels=1:2 keys_zone=appbacktocartcocatch:2m max_size=50m;
#proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri$is_args$args";
#proxy_cache_valid 200 302 10m;
#proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;


upstream appbacktocartco {
#        server localhost:3000;
    server localhost:3001;
}


server {
     listen 145.239.24.196:80;
     server_name app.backtocart.co;

     location / {

       proxy_cache appbacktocartcocatch;

       proxy_set_header   Host $host;
       proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
       proxy_pass         http://appbacktocartco;
       proxy_read_timeout 90;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.backtocart.co/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.backtocart.co/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

}
```

And here is the general nginx config

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
         multi_accept on;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;


        proxy_cache_path  /home/html_catch  levels=1:2 keys_zone=appbacktocartcocatch:2m max_size=50m;
        proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri$is_args$args";
        proxy_cache_valid 200 302 10m;
        proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;




    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;




}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking Nginx logs it turned out that there was no more free space on `root`.
Clearing up space, solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I can provide a different take on this. I had the same issue, but my solution was to accept traffic on port 80 via my firewall.